# how to get background locations updates after reboot?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to develop an iPhone app that retrieves the user location constantly. Even if the user reboots the device or kills the app. I have set the location background mode on the `.plist` file and create the location manager with the following options:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager!.distanceFilter = 100
    locationManager!.activityType = .Fitness
    locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
    locationManager!.delegate = self

    locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

    return true

}
```

I receive location updates, but if I reboot the device the location updates stop and wont start again until you start the app again.

How can I restart the location updates after a reboot?

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a non-jailbroken app, **you can't**.
You have to understand that iOS apps are very strictly sandboxed. You app can't decide to re-launch itself or start a background service when killed or already in the background.
You will have to reconsider this feature.

**EDIT:**
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20508435/598812) from [danielbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144632/danielbeard), if your app was monitoring significant location changes with `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, iOS will wake it up even after a reboot. But if the user manually killed your app, iOS will not restart it.

Comment: Do significant location changes or region monitoring work after reboot?

Comment: I edited my answer to include significant location changes.

Comment: And If I periodically send a remote notification to wake up the app and try to retrieve location updates again?

Comment: It won't work. You can't start location updates from the background. startUpdatingLocation() has to be called when your app is in the foreground.